# Is there any advantage to using encrypted DNS on a VPN server

Tags: vpn, dns, openvpn, dnssec

I have a personal OpenVPN server. I am worried that the fact the DNS resolution coming out of the server isn't encrypted, since I am the only one that uses the server at the moment, attribution isn't very hard. As such is there any advantage to enabling one the the Encrypted DNS protocols on the server - would that work and if so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Even if thousands of people were using the server, attribution would not be hard because IP:port combinations are unique (this is how NAT works).

Comment: @forest true, but how does that apply here?

Comment: @multithr3at3d I was just pointing it out, since OP seems concerned about attribution.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using DNSCrypt and DNSSec directly on your client PC. There is no reason I can see to shift this to your VPN server, and it is probably a lot harder to set up. If you however for some reason have clients using your VPN, that would not be able/not know how to set these up themselves, then this may be worthwhile.

Comment: Although to do it on the VPN server, you'd have to install a DNS server on the there and force the clients to use it.

Comment: @multithr3at3d Exactly. I did not go to the details of setting it up both because I don't know much about it and because it is a bit out of scope for this question. It would deserve a separate one on different SE.